# Find multiple words in notepad++

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, notepad++

I'd like to find exactly ("Match whole word only" function) for multiple keyword in Notepad++ (or any other application).

When I tried enable regular expression setting to search multiple string `stringa|stringb`, but the "Match whole word only" function was disabled ...

For example:

```
testSQLstring
>Test<
/SQLTest/
.SQL.
```

The result for "Match whole word only" for "Test" and "SQL" should be:

```
>Test<
.SQL.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set word boundaries with `\b`. http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

`\b(SQL|Test)\b`
this will match just 'SQL' or just 'Test'

`^.*\b(SQL|Test)\b.*$` this will match the entire line including the given word(s)

Comment: Thank you so much!

You rock!